# Friend callback функция-член класса C++

Tags: c++, классы, callback

```
class A
{ 
    ...
    protected:
      void someMethod(tPvFrame* pData){  value = 1;  }

    private:
     int value;
     friend void func(tPvFrame* pData);
};

------------------------cpp-file-----------------------

....

void func(someStruct* pData)
{
   A* someClass = (A*)pData->Context[0];

   if(A)
     A->someMethod(pData);
}
```

Не понимаю до конца как работает этот механизм... Объясните пожалуйста, если кто-то знает.

Comment: Из приведенного вами кода не ясно, при чем здесь вообще какой-то массив `Context` и откуда он взялся. И почему в объявлении функции параметр имеет тип `tPvFrame *`, а в определении вдруг какой-то `someStruct *`?

Answer (score 2):

```
friend void func(tPvFrame* pData);
```

Это свободная функция, а не член класса. Самая обычная, просто - в силу `friend` - имеющая полный доступ ко всем внутренностям класса `A`, включая те, которые `private`.

Кстати, что-то не верится, что ваш cpp скомпилируется - `friend` вне класса смысла не имеет...

Comment: Внес правку. Получается, что если func используется как callback функция, в которую мы по определённым причинам не можем явно передать ссылку на экземпляр класса, то все это шаманство с приведением массива в теле функции необходимо лишь для того, что бы вызвать метод экземпляра класса как бы "неявно" ?

Comment: Фактически да. Из приведенного фрагмента неясно, можно ли было сделать функцию принимающей указатель на экземпляр класса и обойтись без приведения типов.